# What does DNN mean in a TensorFlow Estimator.DNNClassifier?

Tags: tensorflow, terminology, tensorflow-estimator

I'm guessing that `DNN` in the sense used in `TensorFlow` means "[deep neural network](http://www.abbreviations.com/DNN)". But I find this deeply confusing since the notion of a "deep" neural network seems to be in wide use elsewhere to mean a network with typically several convolutional and/or associated layers (ReLU, pooling, dropout, etc).

In contrast,  the first instance many people will encounter this term (in the [tfEstimator Quickstart example code](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator)) we find:

```
# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
  classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                          hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                          n_classes=3,
                                          model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

This sounds suspiciously shallow, and even more suspiciously like an old-style multilayer perceptron ([MLP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron)) network. However, there is no mention of `DNN` as an alternative term on that close-to-definitive source. So is a `DNN` in the TensorFlow `tf.estimator` context actually an `MLP`? Documentation on the `hidden_units` parameter suggests this is the case:

- **hidden_units:** Iterable of number hidden units per layer. All layers are fully connected. Ex. [64, 32] means first layer has 64 nodes and second one has 32.

That has MLP written all over it. Is this understanding correct? Is `DNN` therefore a misnomer, and if so should `DNNClassifier` ideally be deprecated in favour of `MLPClassifier`? Or does `DNN` stand for something other than *deep neural network*?

Comment: This may clear things up https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/182734/130598

Comment: @Maxim ... or it may muddy the waters :-) The accepted answer to that question more or less points out that a `deep neural network` is an imprecise term without definition. It then show two pictures of what are undeniably an MLPs, varying only in their numbers of (multiple) layers... but goes on to describe all sorts of other possibilities too.

Comment: Well, it's more or less clear for me. One can call it either a deep network or an MLP. DNN is a much more common term nowadays, so I'm not surprised tensorflow devs chose that name. It doesn't contract with deep CNNs, RNNs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give me your definition of "deep" neural network and you get your answer.

But yes, it is simply a MLP and a proper naming would be MLPclassifier indeed. But this does not sounds as cool as the current name.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your definition of DNN is a [bit misleading](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/intro.html).

There are several architectures of deep neural networks. Inclussive Deep Feedforward Networks is nothing more than a multilayered MLP, plus [some techniques to make them attractive](http://deeplearningbook.org).

Some works have used "DNNs" to span all Deep Learning architectures, however, by convention, "DNNs" are used to refer to architectures that use deep forward propagation networks, also called Deep Feedforward Networks

The most important example of a Deep Learning Model is the Profound Net Feedforward or Multilayer Perceptron (MLP). MLP is just a mathematical function that maps some sets of input values to output values. The function is formed by the composition of many simpler functions. You can relate each application of a different mathematical function to provide a new representation of the input.

Therefore, it makes sense that this estimator is called DNNClassifier

My advice is to read [this book here](http://deeplearningbook.org).

Comment: My advice is to read my question :-) This is not about what `DNN` means in general - it is ONLY about what `DNNClassifier` means in the TensorFlow context. It is clear to me that if the network must be fully connected, then it is an old-style MLP network, and is therefore a badly named subset of wide `DNN` means in a wider context. I'm accepting the other answer :-)